# Joomla 3.0.2 to 3.0.3 upgrade causes blank front and back end

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

Tried to upgrade Joomla site from 3.0.2 to 3.0.3 using the web interface and this caused the front and backend to go down. The logs read as follows:

```
[31-Dec-2013 09:08:19 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/nicsca/public_html/libraries/gantry/core/gantrybrowser.class.php on line 91
[31-Dec-2013 09:08:20 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/nicsca/public_html/modules/mod_roknavmenu/lib/common/RokBrowserCheck.php on line 22
[31-Dec-2013 09:40:19 America/Regina] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/nicsca/public_html/plugins/system/remember/remember.php on line 94
```

I'm at a lost (fairly new to Joomla) and any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Joomla 3.0 has not been supported for a long time, you should be on 3.2.1.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about an upgrade to 3.2.1, give I currently have no access to the backend? FTP is still up.

Comment: Wait you tried to update without access to the back end? How did you run the database changes and delete the unused files? Do you have shell?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I had access to the back-end, and used the Joomla update available on there. I chose to perform the update and the progress bar went along nicely until it was done. I was redirected to a domain ending in "=update.finalize" where the page just hung. Now neither the front end or the back end load/display anything.

Comment: Okay, so if you were using the updater how did you end up with 3.0.3? 
So a couple of things. 
1. Edit configuration.php to put error reporting on development.  See if you get any errors and deal with them i.e. unpublish any plugins generating errors.
2. Since you are having Gantry/rockettheme issues, try switching to  Protostar and Isis (also check the RT support site). 3. Check the deleted files list in com_admin script.php and make sure they have all been deleted.

Comment: The updater told me that a new version was avaliable; 3.0.3. I thought it was odd, but sort of assumed you had to go through each version sequentially. The error I get with reporting on development is:         _Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/nicsca/public_html/plugins/system/remember/remember.php on line 94_      Might give disabling the remember plugin a go

Comment: If it's possible, for the time being, I'd like to revert the update and go back to 3.0.2. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm taking it that you did not do a backup?

Comment: No... Funny thing is, I thought the update would be a really simple process, and was doing to to install Akeeba...

Comment: Update should be simple, but in my experience it really depends on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Since remember is giving you a fatal error, unpublish that plugin by editing the extensions table in your database, at least then your site should load.

Update:
It is very strange that the updater is telling you 3.0.3.  IF you go to the options for the Joomla update component, what settings are showing in the pop up?

Comment: I can't check since the back end is down. Do you know if there is a way to revert back to 3.0.2

Comment: Can you look in the database? Try disabling remember first, then you should be able to login.

Comment: Is it possible to disable without access to PHPMyadmin? I don't currently have the credentials

Comment: I've got hold of the credentials and now the front end is up and running after I disabled the remember plugin. The back end is still down, and the error I'm given is   _Fatal error: Call to a member function checkSession() on a non-object in /home/nicsca/public_html/plugins/user/joomla/joomla.php on line 189_    there's nothing on google about this. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok.. Interestingly, although It told me it was updating to 3.0.3, if I check the version using _http://www.whitefirdesign.com/resources/check-what-version-of-joomla-you-are-running.html_ I'm now running 3.2.1 which is great news. Parts of the backend are also working; For example to module manager, however other parts throw errors

Comment: What errors? It still sounds to me like you have a problem with old files maybe.  Are you using the core template in the back end?  3.2 and 3.2.1 both have changes to remember me so I suspect that whatever was causing your error there is probably the same source as for the other errors.

Comment: Various errors usually relating to tables not existing. Ie, when I go to settings->Edit Account I get _Table 'nicsca_jool.jool_tags' doesn't exist_  Sounds like you could be right, but I have no idea how to correct this. Also, under the extensions tab, there's no option to upload extensions.

Comment: Go to Extensions, Database and click Fix.

Comment: Urgh, rather typically, that is a section I cannot access: _Table 'nicsca_jool.jool_content_types' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW COLUMNS IN `jool_content_types` WHERE field = 'content_history_options'_  Thankyou so much for your help!

Comment: Ah, no worries, found the answer here: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=826530 incase anyone else is having a similar issue! Thanks again for all your help!